# WPF C# Refresh/Rebind Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to refresh a listbox in my WPF application and it does not seem to be working.

If I reload the application after adding values the values do get added.

I have a variable and a property called 'listboxData':

```
    ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> listboxData = new ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> ListBoxData
    {
        get
        {
            return listboxData;
        }        
    }
```

I have bound the values of my Listbox to this property:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListSrc" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListBoxData}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
```

When the user adds a value this code gets called:

```
public void RefreshListbox()
{

        listboxData.Clear();

        foreach (podiaPublish.Marker pMarker in Global.gChapter.MarkerList)
        {
            foreach (podiaPublish.Content pContent in pMarker.ContentList)
            {

                //FOR SLIDES THAT HAVE JUST BEEN IMPORTED, THERE WILL BE NO FILES ON THE SERVER (SO NO CHECKSUMS AVAILABLE)

                if (File.Exists(Global.TempFolder + "\\" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pContent.AlternateMarkup) ? pContent.Markup : pContent.AlternateMarkup)))
                {
                    //KLUDGE TO RESIZE THE THUMBNAILS
                    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(Global.TempFolder + "\\" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pContent.AlternateMarkup) ? pContent.Markup : pContent.AlternateMarkup), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(fs);
                    var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bm.GetHbitmap(),
                                                                        IntPtr.Zero,
                                                                        Int32Rect.Empty,
                                                                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
                    );
                    bm.Dispose();
                    fs.Close();

                    if (pContent.Markup.Contains(".png"))
                    {
                        var brush = new ImageBrush(bitmapSource);

                        var lb1 = new TempDataType()
                        {
                            Name = pContent.Markup,
                            BackgroundImage = brush
                        };

                        listboxData.Add(lb1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I first clear the 'listboxData' and then as you can see in the foreach loop I re-add the new values. When debugging this returns the correct values.

EDIT:

The properties of the listbox get bound in the :

```
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type tt:TempDataType}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Background="{Binding BackgroundImage}"
                CornerRadius="3"
                Height="120">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding BackgroundImage}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The TempDataType Class is structured like this:

```
public class TempDataType : ITimeLineDataItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
    public ImageBrush BackgroundImage { get; set; }
    public Boolean TimelineViewExpanded { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do name and backgroundImage throw a property changed ?

Comment: @Muds No I don't do that. I just have the the code behind and a property binding to it.

Comment: can you show us code for TempDataType.Name ?

Comment: @Muds I have added some code which shows how the BackgroundImage and Name get bound to the properties of the listbox and also the way TempDataType Class is structured.

Comment: you need to implement INotifyPropertyCHanged in your TempDataType and then raise property changed for your bound properties

Comment: @Muds Would you be able to show me an example of this?

Comment: Ben I would want you to write the code to update the collection first, then I will try to fix it, show me code where you update the collection. not this one where you clear and add new items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100033/discussion-between-ben-clarke-and-muds).

Answer (score 0):

I trust you are using MVVM pattern but couldn't see property changed event (INotifyPropertyChanged)  in your code any way if you are not using MVVM then directly use Listbox object to add items in the list:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> ListBoxData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.listboxData;
        }
        set
        {
                this.listboxData = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ListBoxData);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't seem to find the using for the RaisePropertyChanged event ... Do you know what this is?

Answer (score 0):

See this code just I have implemented the interface in viewmodel:

```
class YourViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //method to fire the property changed event ...
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    //To raise the changes in property ...
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpression);
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I am not using ViewModel's for this? I need to be able to refresh without a ViewModel.

Comment: in this case you need to keep/access the instance of  ListSrc DDL and directly refresh the item source one get new list box data.

Comment: I am refreshing the listboxData list but the question is the ListBox on the page isn't refreshing.

Comment: Ben, it will not autometically update target object untill you not fire PropertyChanged event but in your case you are not using MVVM so does not apply it. to fix you need to write this code ** ListSrc.ItemsSource= ListBoxData;** in end of  RefreshListbox() method.